# mySql - search query based on keywords

Tags: php, mysql

I wasn't able to find anything that really helped me out with this.
I have a database with the following structure:

[image]

and a simple query to search and display some results from the DB:

```
if ($_REQUEST['search']) {
    $q = $_REQUEST['search'];
    $q_comma = explode(", ", $q);
    $where_in_set = '';
    $count = count($q_comma);

    foreach ($q_comma as $q) {
        $counter++;
        if ($counter == $count) {
            $where_in_set .= "FIND_IN_SET('$q','keywords')";
        } else {
            $where_in_set .= "FIND_IN_SET('$q','keywords') AND ";
        }
    }


    $sql_res = "select link, description, keyword from myDB where $where_in_set or description like '%$q%'";
```

This code works, but not really as I wanted.

In the keyword column, I have different comma separated keywords, and i'd like to be able to search for them even if the order is different.

Here's an example: Let's say I have into my keyword column

> Google, Facebook, twitter

With my current code if I type Google, I can see the result, but if i type twitter, I don't see it.

Is there anything I can do to make it work without taking into account the order of the keywords, but having a pretty fast search as well?

Any help will be really appreciated.

PS. I'd like to keep only one DB if possible, cause I read about creating a new table with only ID and keywords, and on my search join the tables on the ID's, but I would prefer a better solution if possible.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Some updates:

1. as pointed out by @Frayne Konok, i have the query in lowcase and all the value in the db in lowcase as well, so case cannot be the problem
2. As suggested by @mkaatman, i wrapped `keyword` column around backticks (`)
3. I changed my query so that now it looks like the one suggested by @user2272989 in the answer

So my query now looks like this:

```
select link, description, keyword from myDB
where (FIND_IN_SET('google',`keyword`) or
       FIND_IN_SET('facebook', `keyword`) or 
       FIND_IN_SET('twitter', `keyword`))
       OR description like 'google, facebook, twitter'
```

And it is returning values even if the order is different, but it is not showing only the one i want.
For example, if i write twitter, google, facebook, i have as a return something like 28 rows, where only 2 have all of the three words as a keyword, while the other my have only one or two

**EDIT 2 - Updates**

I just want to "reopen" this question since I didn't manage to solve this. If I change all the keywords into an object, will then be better to use them as keywords? or what is the absolute best and more reliable way to search a database for keywords? Having different DBs and use an INNER JOIN?

At this point I'm willing to change the structure and the code if it helps.

Thanks

Comment: Does this work? `SELECT FIND_IN_SET('Twitter','Google,Facebook,Twitter'); ` I would `var_dump($q);` right inside the foreach to make sure you're checking what you think you're checking. Also, I don't believe keywords should be surrounded in quotes.

Comment: case may be the problem, you may try `LOWER` in your `description`. ex: `LOWER(description) like '%$q%'`. also `strtolower` the `$q`

Comment: @mkaatman without keywords in quotes i have a syntax error saying "unknown column keywords in table"

Comment: @FrayneKonok I am already lowering the query and my DB, but thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Nick  you need to use the backtick instead of quotes. `

Comment: @mkaatman ok now column is not unknown anymore. I'm going to edit my question with some updates

Comment: @Nick, Edit your question to add the output from `echo $sql_res;` so we can see what your query looks like.

Comment: @mkaatman i'm testing it using mysql workbench now, i want to check number of rows and times first

Comment: Does this query work in workbench? I'm assuming you only want to find results with all three keywords in this instance. `select link, description, keyword from myDB
where (FIND_IN_SET('google',\`keyword\`) AND
       FIND_IN_SET('facebook', \`keyword\`) AND 
       FIND_IN_SET('twitter', \`keyword\`))`

Comment: using AND instead of OR does not show any results at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this structure and query here:

```
$q = $_REQUEST['search'];
$q_comma = array_filter(explode(' ', str_replace(',', ' ', $q)));
$count = count($q_comma);
$dbQuery = "select id, link, description, tags from db where ";
$searchTerms = '';

foreach ($q_comma as $q) {
    $counter++;
    if ($counter == 1) {
        $searchTerms .= "tags LIKE '%$q%'";
    } else {
        $searchTerms .= "and tags LIKE '%$q%'";
    }
}


$sql_res = $dbQuery . $searchTerms;
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql_res) or die(mysqli_error($db));
$return_arr = array();
$data = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "Nothing";
} else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
$sql_res = "select link, description, keyword from myDB 
      where (FIND_IN_SET('yahoo',keyword) or
             FIND_IN_SET('twitter',keyword)) or 
             description like '%$q%'";
```

You are using `AND` condition in `FIND_IN_SET`

Comment: With your example doesn't really seams to filter as i need...if i type google, facebook, it displays all the right rows, but if i add for example twitter, it still shows all the rows even if i only have 1 with all of the 3 keywords togheter